# Why Android Studio is creating two fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So here's the problem, when I create a new project using Basic Activity template it generates two fragments and every page or tutorial I've seen it's not generated. Is it something normal? How to I to avoid Android Studio creating this two fragments?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That started in version 3.6 of Android Studio. I believe they're trying to promote their [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/), where the principle is to use one single Activity (host) and many Fragments (for all the other screens of the app).

As the other answers have suggested, you can either select "Empty Activity" instead or delete these fragments after they're created.

My suggestion would be to try and learn about the new Navigation Component, as it might become the new Standard in the near future.

Comment: @AdriánNúñezMartínez Consider accepting this answer (click on the checkmark to the left of it) if it answers your question so that others know it has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't know why Android Studio does that but if you want just one activity you can start with "Empty Activity" Or just "Add No Activity" option. And then add an activity with the App->New->Activity->Empty Activity.

Comment: I did it, and it creates them two :(

Comment: It is in fact weird. I don't know why it happens, but you can always delete them :) sry I couldn't help.